# how to exclude some tables from being binlogged in mysql?

Tags: mysql, drupal, replication, binary-log

I need to exclude some files from being logged in the binary log to avoid wasting my network bandwidth and time on replication of caching tables.
i know there is

```
[mysqld]
binlog-ignore-db=DB_TO_BE_SKIPPED
```

how can i do so for specific tables (Caching tables)??
is there something like

```
binlog-ignore-table=tbl_boost_cache
```

**** Edit ****
i am using drupal, and there is a functional defect with boost caching in drupal. the binlog files get large exponentially. (sometimes about 100MB/minute!!) and the only one to avoid such cases is to stop logging for these tables
Thanks!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/mysql-binary-log-makes-disk-full.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/mysql-binary-logs-skip-a-table too

Answer (score 1):

mysql has  parameters:

```
replicate-ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name
replicate-wild-ignore-table=db_name.%
```

u can try it

Comment: ok. thanks for your answer.. but this will keep logging caching tables in binlog as well.. the problem is: there is functional defect in drupal caching tables and bin logs get larger exponentially (it gets about 100MB every minute :O ) and thus i need to overcome this defect by stopping logging of these table. any idea is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone finds something better. The only way I could find, a part from using "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0" was to move the table into another database and use the binlog-ignore-db =

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:-

> SET @@session.sql_log_bin=0;
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'
> --other LOAD DATA INFILE options ;
>
> SET @@session.sql_log_bin=1;

Comment: requires SUPER basically and in newer versions became more granular but anyways

Answer (score 0):

I found a feature request on MariaDB's issue tracker. So, this is a feature that many have dreamed about since 2016. You can vote for it.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9353

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34589182)